# Both sides are rendered differently in the mirror

Tags: rendering, mirror

[image]

After making one eyeball, I copied the object to the mirror, and the pupil is showing normally.
On the other hand, the white eyeball part shows a different rendering.

Why are the two rendering views different?
Blender is version 3.1.2. Since I'm just starting out with Blender, it was hard to find the cause on my own. I couldn't find a similar issue on the website either.

Comment: Maybe flipped normals, which does happen with certain mirrors. Edit mode, select all, Normals -> recalculate outside.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's my first time using Blender, so I couldn't find the "recalculate outside" menu. I searched the website and barely applied it, but nothing changed. Any other solutions, please? (sad...)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "copied the object to the mirror" ? - It looks as if you might have two eyeballs in the same position.

Comment: @Caco Sorry. Here. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/normals.html

Comment: Thank you all. I found the problem. Contrary to what was described in the lecture I was watching, the texture coordinates were linked as generated in the node. I connected this with UV and the problem was solved. It seems that the problem was caused by a mismatch between the versions of my blender and the blender of the course.